# Avoid line break after macro

Tags: floats, context

The following example produces a line break after the second text.

```
\define[2]\smallfigure{\placefigure[margin][#1]{#2}{!}}%

\starttext 
text text\smallfigure{fig1}{A}text text 
\stoptext
```

[image: linebreak_example]

The [ConTeXt FAQ](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/FAQ#Why_is_there_a_line-break_in_the_output_after_some_commands.3F) addresses this explicitly. However, although the problem seems identical, changing the macro to

```
\define[2]\smallfigure{\dontleavehmode\placefigure[margin][#1]{#2}{!}}%
```

does not work as intended and avoiding the macro altogether

```
\starttext 
text text\dontleavehmode\placefigure[margin][]{A}{!}text text 
\stoptext
```

does not work either. Is there a way to avoid the line break?

Comment: How about inserting the figure at the beginning of the paragraph?

Comment: I would normally do that. In this case I prepare documents with different layouts, but the same content. Then it is advantagous to put the figure exactly where it is also mentioned in the text the first time. Otherwise, I would have to tweak every document by itself. It would be great, if that is possible.

Comment: Would “[What is the ConTeXt or plain TeX equivalent of \nolinebreak?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51063/what-is-the-context-or-plain-tex-equivalent-of-nolinebreak)” help?

Comment: This is a known property of floats and crops up on the mailing list every now and then. If it’s a problem for you, then you might be able to bypass it using the [postponing mechanism](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20120405.112507.e883aec5.en.html). In some cases where you don’t need a caption, the [hangaround environment](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics#Flow_text_around_a_picture) may lead to acceptable results too.

Comment: @phg Could you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Move the `placefigure` call**

One solution would be to place the figure at the beginning of the
paragraph. This keeps the text together.

```
\starttext

\startplacefigure [title=Caption,location=margin]
  \externalfigure [dummy]
\stopplacefigure
text text
text text

\stoptext
```

**Use the [postponing](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startpostponing) mechanism**

The postponing mechanism keeps the text together. However, it
influences the float placement. The float appears on the page after
the text, which might be undesirable.

```
text text
\startpostponing [+1]
  \startplacefigure [title=Caption,location=margin]
    \externalfigure [dummy]
  \stopplacefigure
\stoppostponing
text text
```