# Text and figure side by side in a list in ConTeXt

Tags: context

I want to include some figures on the right of some list items. Here is an example with one figure in the second item:

```
\starttext
\startitemize[n]
    \item first item
    \item \placefigure[right]{none}{\framed[width=1in]{Figure}} \input knuth
    \item third item
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Everything is great except there is a blank line after the item label. How can I remove this blank line so the content of the item is right after the item label?

If I use `\startfiguretext` instead of `\placefigure`:

```
    \item \startfiguretext[right]{none}{\framed[width=1in]{}} \input knuth
    \stopfiguretext
```

Not only is there a blank line after the item label, but the list item is no longer indented.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: It’s a general issue with floats in Context strategies against which are [covered on the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Unexpected_behavior#Float_Insertion_Issues).
Also, possible duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56388/14066).

Comment: The spacing of the float interferes with the spacing of the itemgroup. Without the caption the `\starthanging[location=right]{…}…\stophanging` mechanism would probably do the job.

Comment: @Marco The commands `\starthanging` and `\stophanging` are not recognized. I'm using TeX Live 2012: ConTeXt 2012.05.30 with XeTeX 9.99.99.

Comment: The command is only available in MkIV in combination with LuaTeX.

Comment: I struggled with a similar problem some time ago.  Did you try using `\startitem ... \stopitem` instead of `\item ...` and putting your figure between items?  (I didn't test this, just had this idea.)

Answer (score 2):

@mbork Your suggestion worked like a charm. The code now looks like this:

```
\starttext
\startitemize[n,joinedup]
    \item first item
\stopitemize
\placefigure[right]{none}{\framed[width=1in,height=3in]{Dummy\crlf Figure}}
\startitemize[n,continue]
    \item \input knuth
    \item \input tufte
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: You don't need to stop the itemize; simply put the `\placefigure` **before** the item that you want to float around.

Comment: You are right, just need to put `\placefigure` before the `\item`, although logically this looks as if the `placefigure` belongs to the previous item.