# Suppressing pagebreaks within paragraphs

Tags: page-breaking, context, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid page-breaks inside paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs)

The style spec for a document requires that pagebreaks come between paragraphs *or* list items, so paragraphs are never split across pages. (The content is specced so that paragraphs are always short enough for this to be sane.)

How do I accomplish this? I looked into `\penalty`, which is mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51064/1406), but it appears to be undocumented both on the [ConTeXt Garden wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=penalty&go=Go) and on the [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=ntg-context%40ntg.nl&q=subject%3Apenalty+sort%3Anewest). There are a number of un(der)documented "penalty" commands such as `\widowpenalty` that control various aspects of paragraph breaking, but nothing that I can find that directly controls "to break or not to break" in absolute terms.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21983/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-paragraphs

Comment: @lockstep That does the job! What's the policy on closing when the other question's answers are mostly LaTeX-specific and the sorta-but-not-really-exact duplicate is about ConTeXt? A TEX-native solution works, but context users are going to be seardching with {[tag:context]} to limit noise. If this was closed as a duplicate and linked to the other they'd find your answer (maybe, being the not-accepted answer on a LaTeX question, they might just close it before scrolling down), but it's not an exact duplicate, is it? Should the answer be duplicated here?

Comment: Not sure, I asked a question in chat.

Comment: BTW, if my answer to the linked question was helpful, don't hesitate to upvote it. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep Right! Yes! I was so busy testing it then getting distracted by SE procedure that I forgot to return to upvote. There you go. :)